# Acess array data in elseif ( ) {..} condition from if ( ) {…} condition

Tags: php, arrays, forms, form-submit

I have two form submitting buttons in one form, and I want to use `$uploaded` array in `elseif() {...}` like this `$data ['pic_path'] = $uploaded;`, but it doesn't work. I can only print out `$uploaded` inside of `if () {...}`, or inside the html body. What should I do to save the `$uploaded` in `$data` array? Thanks!

Here's the code:

---

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST[submit_image])) {
    if (!empty($_FILES["files"]["name"][0])) {
        $files = $_FILES["files"];
        //arrarys to include files uploaded successfully and failed
        $uploaded = array();
        $failed = array();
        //access tmp_name arrary
        foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
            $file_tmp = $files["tmp_name"][$position];

            $file_ext = explode(".", $file_name);
            $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

            $file_name_new = uniqid("", true) . "." . $file_ext;
            $file_destination = "uploads/" . $file_name_new;
            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                $uploaded[$position] = $file_destination;
            } else {
                $failed[$position] = "error";
            }   
        } 
        print_r($uploaded);
    }
} elseif (isset($_POST[submit_post])) {
        $data = array();
        $data['comments'] =  $_POST['comments'];
        //$data ['pic_path'] = $uploaded;
        //print_r($uploaded);
}   
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
            <input type="submit" name="submit_image"/>
            <textarea name="comments"></textarea>           
            <button type="submit" name="submit_post">Submit Your Post</button>                 
        </form>         
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$uploaded` only exists in the if statement you declared it in. You will need to loop through files again in the elseif or move your declaration of `$uploaded` and `$failed` as well as the for loop that populates them out of that if block so the variables are accessible in both paths.

Edit - Try this:

```
 if (!empty($_FILES["files"]["name"][0]) ) {
        $files = $_FILES["files"];
        //arrarys to include files uploaded successfully and failed
        $uploaded = array();
        $failed = array();
        //access tmp_name arrary
        foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
            $file_tmp = $files["tmp_name"][$position];

            $file_ext = explode(".", $file_name);
            $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

            $file_name_new = uniqid("", true) . "." . $file_ext;
            $file_destination = "uploads/" . $file_name_new;
            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                $uploaded[$position] = $file_destination;
            } else {
                $failed[$position] = "error";
            }   
        } 
        print_r($uploaded);
    }

if (isset($_POST[submit_post])) {
        $data = array();
        $data['comments'] =  $_POST['comments'];
        $data ['pic_path'] = $uploaded;
}
```

Comment: I have put `$uploaded = array();` outside of the `if () {...} elseif ( ) {...}`. But still `print_r ($uploaded) ` only works in `if ( ) {...} ` not in `elseif () {...}`.

Comment: I edited my answer with code that should work. Try that out.

Comment: Thanks for your editing, I've tried but `$data ['pic_path'] = $uploaded;` value is still empty. And it seems that getting rid of `if (isset($_POST[submit_post])) { ...}` as well will work. However, I don't know how much it will affect the form validation. But I'll give it a go in my complete code :)

Comment: One possible cause is that when you reload the page after submitting the files, the $_FILES var is garbage collected since you go out of scope, you will need to make sure you're preserving that data by injecting it back into the form when the page reloads.

Comment: Actually after looking into it more, files cannot be repopulate back into the form, you have two options. The first would be to avoid requiring a form submit for each file and instead use JavaScript to either allow multiple uploads by creating a new field each time, or you could use JavaScript and Ajax to upload them from the form itself. The other option is to save the files temporarily and create some sort of ID system to identify that those files belong to that users form and remove them after a set time. Personally I would just use JavaScript though to and then just have one submit button.